# Delayed Apple in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

Does Apple in-app purchase support delayed payments? People press pay, Apple charges the amount, then we can approve/decline the transaction, and then Apple can capture or refund the transaction?

We need to verify that people giving us money are allowed to do so. We don't want to have to reverse the charge after the fact if we find out they are not eligible to pay us.

I did not find any refund API or subscription trial hack for it.

Comment: To my knowledge, you will have to do this checking *before* submitting the payment processing to Apple. On what basis do you make the decision? Do you have more info on which to make this decision *after* submitting payment processing to Apple?

Comment: Your Knowledge is right, I dig into myself to the Apple purchase policy and API, an there is no way to do it. Stripe and Paypal can refund or auth and charge, but Apple can't. We had to work out a pretty painful conversation method to handle the feature.
To see the full picture, it's like a feature request what we can accept or refuse, but it potentially could be flooded by internet communities like 4chan. We wanted to use the purchase as a filter of serious users.

Comment: @rosszember if you can explain your solution that would be great

Comment: @Itayk On the end of the day we decided to use Stripe, they support refound natively.
Maybe you can use some kind of gate, that only opens if you allowed the request and then users can pay.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having the user enter his credit card number.